# is Auto-merging feature in Azure Devops available?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Hi I am migrating repo from bitbucket to Azure DevOps, wanted to have the auto merging feature in bitbucket to be in ADO, is this feature available in Azure DevOps, if so, how to enable it?

Auto Merging feature in Azure DevOps, how to enable? is it with the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that Azure DevOps doesn't support the same Branch Auto-merging feature as Bitbucket.

In Azure DevOps, we need to manually create the Pull Request to merger the changes from one branch to another.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest)